# ReactJS calling function twice inside child component fails to set parent state twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue where I want to save the data from a particular fieldset with the default values on `componentDidMount()`.

The data saving happens in the parent component, after it is sent up from the child component. However, as React's setState() is asynchronous, it is only saving data from one of the fields. I have outlined a skeleton version of my problem below. Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
// Parent Component

class Form extends Component {
  super(props);
  this.manageData = this.manageData.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    formData: {}
  }
}


manageData(data) {
  var newObj = {
    [data.name]: data.value
   }

  var currentState = this.state.formData;
  var newState = Object.assign({}, currentState, newObj);

  this.setState({
    formData: newState, // This only sets ONE of the fields from ChildComponent because React delays the setting of state.
  )};

render() {
  return (
    <ChildComponent formValidate={this.manageData} />
  )
}



// Child Component

class ChildComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    const fieldA = {
      name: 'Phone Number',
      value: '123456678'
    },
    fieldB = {
      name: 'Email Address',
      value: 'john@example.com'
    }

    this.props.formValidate(fieldA);
    this.props.formValidate(fieldB)
  }


  render() {
    /// Things happen here.
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) ?

Comment: Hi @AsafAviv - the project itself is quite large and I have minified what is actually happening. Is there something specific you need to better comment on this?

Comment: Can you atleast format this 2 components as working components ?

Comment: React groups multiple `setState` calls together in most cases. But it looks like that isn't happening here because they're being called from within two different scopes.

Comment: @Adam it looks like they actually do collide, I've added a `setTimeout` to the second `formValidate` and it appears to be working

Comment: Right, that would be because React isn't grouping them. That means the first `setState` is running which would prevent the second one from running unless it was queued with `setTimeout` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks everyone! You're all so helpful! I should use Stack Overflow more often! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `manageData` to this

```
manageData(data) {
  const newObj = {
    [data.name]: data.value
  };

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    formData: {
      ...prevState.formData,
      ...newObj
    }
  }));
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand why this worked - but it did! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, JSanchezIO actually provided a good explanation, but in short we are merging our previous state with our new state through `this.setState` callback `prevState` which holds our previous state

Answer (score 2):

You're already answering you're own question. React handles state asynchronously and as such you need to make sure you use the current component's state when `setState` is invoked. Thankfully the team behind React is well-aware of this and have provided an overload for the `setState` method. I would modify your `manageData` call to the following:

```
manageData(data) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const nextState = Object.assign({}, prevState);

        nextState.formData[data.name] = data.value;

        return nextState;
    });
}
```

This overload for the `setState` takes a function whose first parameter is the component's current state at the time that the `setState` method is invoked. Here is the link where they begin discussing this form of the `setState` method.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! @AsafAviv's response was more concise and worked for me. I'm sure yours takes care of it too. And thanks for the extra info!

Comment: Also - my manageData() method actually contains a lot more logic, so your method may have required quite a bit of refactoring. But thanks for the insights! Appreciate it!